# Python - Creating a list of links that support user input

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

Extracted href attributes with BeautifulSoup4 (also using urllib2, webbrowser)...
I would like an output similar to this, that supports user input:

Any ideas?

```
(0) - http://www.example1.com
(1) - http://www.example2.com
(2) - http://www.example3.com
(3) - http://www.example4.com
(4) - http://www.example5.com
(5) - http://www.example6.com

>>> 0 (opens http://www.example1.com in browser)
>>> 1 (opens http://www.example2.com in browser)
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html anyone? :) seems notable for this question :)

Answer (score 0):

You could write your links to an html file, and use something like `os.popen('firefox file.html')` to open the file so that the user might click the links directly, or you could use the `raw_input()` function to ask the user for some option, and then call firefox (or other browser) with command line arguments, again using `os.popen()`.

This worked for me (an example only):

```
import os

link1 = 'www.google.com'
link2 = 'www.yahoo.com'

s = raw_input("1 = %s\n2 = %s\n\n" % (link1, link2))

if s == '1':
    os.popen("firefox %s" % link1)
elif s == '2':
    os.popen("firefox %s" % link2)
```